# Trouble getting an array to display my minimum and maximum inputs in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I am currently working on an application where the user inputs 10 integers into an array and then clicks a button to display the integers in ascending or descending order from highest to lowest, however it is not working as intended. When I click the button that should sort them, nothing happens. Can anyone give some insight? Here is my current code.

```
 Function intInput() As Integer
    Const intMax As Integer = 9
    Dim intArray(intMax) As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer 'Loop counter

    For intCount = 0 To intMax 'Run intCount through intMax 10 times
        intArray(intCount) = CInt(InputBox("Please enter an integer: ")) 'input the integers and store them into the array element
    Next
    lstArray.Items.Clear()

    For intCount = 0 To intMax
        lstArray.Items.Add(intArray(intCount)) 'add the integers to the list
    Next
    Return intArray(intCount)
End Function

Function intHighest() As Integer
    Const intMax As Integer = 9
    Dim intArray(intMax) As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer 'Loop counter
    Dim intHigh As Integer


    intHigh = intArray(0)

    For intCount = 1 To (intArray.Length - 1)
        If intArray(intCount) > intHigh Then
            intHigh = intArray(intCount)
        End If
    Next
    Return intHigh
End Function

Function intLow() As Integer
    Const intMax As Integer = 9
    Dim intArray(intMax) As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer 'Loop counter
    Dim intLowest As Integer


    intLowest = intArray(9)

    For intCount = 1 To (intArray.Length - 1)
        If intArray(intCount) < intLowest Then
            intLowest = intArray(intCount)
        End If
    Next
    Return intLowest
End Function

Private Sub btnInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInput.Click
    intInput()

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstArray.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    intHighest()
    intLow()


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I cant see any code that sorts or displays

Comment: And redeclaring the array inside the intHighest and intLow doesn't help too

Comment: What would be your suggested approach? I'm going through my book to try to find where I went wrong but would appreciate advice from those more experienced than I.

Comment: You need to learn about Scope.  The intArrays you declare inside subs only exists there.  You need a module level array var.  Your hi-low procs are evaluating an empty array.  Set a breakpoint and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to find the minimum and maximum values in an array, and to sort the values in an array.

```
Dim arrNum() As Integer = {3, 1, 2} 'Create an integer array
Dim minNum As Integer = arrNum.Min 'Get the minimum value
Dim maxNum As Integer = arrNum.Max 'Get the maximum value
Array.Sort(arrNum) 'Sort the array
```